# php xor operator not working as expected

Tags: php, xor

I have the following code. If i run each condition separately it works fine but soon as i add the 'xor' or 'or' or '||' operators neither seem to match.

I know its going to be something simple im missing out but can't spot it. Am i using this operator wrong?

```
if ($usercurrentpassword['password'] != $currentpasswordmd5 xor $usercurrentpassword['password'] != $currentpasswordsha1){
                    $a = "Current passwords do not match";
                    return $a;
                }
```

Comment: You're probably experiencing order of presidence issues.  There's no bracketing in your if statement so I can't guess at what your intended order of execution is.

Comment: already tried it with bracket like the comment below but the same. If i change the statement to only check against one variable it works fine but not either or.

Comment: Also, the algorithm seems to be wrong - if the password hasn't got the same MD5 nor the same SHA1, it won't echo anything. Maybe the problem is in how you "encode" your thought? What is the algorithm meant to do?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, the XOR (exclusive disjunction) operator in PHP (and many other languages) is the **caret**: **^**. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use brackets:

```
if (($usercurrentpassword['password'] != $currentpasswordmd5) xor ($usercurrentpassword['password'] != $currentpasswordsha1)) {
```